"Spirit of God" & "God is Spirit", but no "God of Spirit" or "Spirit is God", - what does that mean for trinity understanding?
Verses from YLT:


The Spirit of God hath made me, and the breath of the Almighty hath given me life. — Job 33:4
Neither will I hide my face any more from them: for I have poured out my spirit upon the house of Israel, saith the Lord GOD. — Ezekiel 39:29
God is a Spirit, and those worshipping Him, in spirit and truth it doth behove to worship.' — John 4:24 (YLT's italics)


Considering the notion based on whole NT that Jesus is [son of] God, these are also relevant:


I [John] indeed did baptize you with water, but he [someone unknown to John yet] shall baptize you with [by] the Holy Ghost.' — Mark 1:8 (my brackets)
and immediately coming up from the water, he saw the heavens dividing, and the Spirit as a dove coming down upon him; — Mark 1:10



Question
If, according to the text, God is Spirit, Spirit is of God, and God act with his Spirit same as Jesus do, and as there are no instances of "God of Spirit" and "Spirit is God" in the text, so:
— is it right not only to say, but also to understand, that both 'Jesus is God' and 'God is Jesus' in most cases are correct notions, in light of the full corpus of the Scripture, — while 'God of Spirit', 'Spirit is God', 'Jesus of Spirit' and 'Spirit is Jesus' all are wrong in any possible case?

Note: I'm not very interested in statements that were made by proponents of any side of the Great Schism back in the days, just because from my opinion their mutual misunderstanding was and is institutional (i.e. based on local practices, local habits, local problems, local language, etc), and not scriptural at all, what makes them both right to some extent, and both wrong in a sense that subject of trinity in their fight was, for both sides, just a good official excuse of the happening matter. I am interested if my present understanding contradicts the Scripture or not, maybe I'm missing something.
Thanks!

Actually, "God of spirits" occurs in Num 16:22 and 27:16.

@Dottard, but spirits do not act with their God as God act with his Spirit; seems that I should think how to make my question more clear. Anyway I had not knew that, thank you.

It is not clear what you are asking. You are asking, in effect, multiple questions which is confusing. I suggest you take one text at a time and ask one question about it. Asking why the bible does not say things is pointless and off-topic.

According to us, Christians, The Holy Trinity is constituted by Three distinct Persons with the same will. And also there is a difference between the Holy Spirit (He is God) and another spirit (which is NOT God). "God is a Spirit" from John 4:24 is referring to the spiritual nature of God and not necessary to the Person of the Holy Spirit. There is more to say, but remember that you should always look at the context of the Bible verses.

This is a systematic theology question, not an exegetical question about one passage, which unfortunately means that it is off topic here.

To resolve this question requires a massive examination of the whole Bible, to glean everything there is to know about the Holy Spirit, and with no initial reference to creeds or dogmas that came after the last book of the Bible was written. Once that has been done, then, perhaps, can it be seen how the Holy Spirit fits into the doctrine of the Trinity.
My answer is that it's best not to tackle matters back to front. Start in Genesis 1:2 - "And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters" (the very first mention), and collate all other texts until the very last mention, in Revelation 22:17 - "And the Spirit and the Bride say 'Come'." Whole books have already been written, doing that.
This is a massive topic, and cannot be answered on the Hermeneutic site, which requires 1 or 2 biblical texts to be examined. If the question could be changed to refine it to something suitable for Hermeneutics, answers could home in on specific points raised. The only answer I offer here is that the Holy Spirit is profoundly important in order to understand the Trinity doctrine, for without his teaching and illumination, we only have our own ideas and ways of looking at scripture. But, as Jesus said, after his return to heaven, he sent the Holy Spirit to remind his followers of what he had said, and to "guide them into all truth" (John 14:17 & 16:13-14). If our estimation of the Holy Spirit is less than that declared in the Bible, we cannot understand what is needful to know.

The arguments or justifications of the traditional teachings of men for the Trinity as three persons in one being breaks apart when we investigate the meaning of the word "Spirit."
The word translated as "Spirit" in Gen. 1:2 is Strong's H7307 "ruach."  It is defined as spirit, wind or breath, and is used as wind, breath, exhalation, life, and is derived from the root "רוּחַ" which means to breathe or blow.  It corresponds to G4151 "pneuma" in the NT which is also translated as "Spirit" which means wind or breath.
Therefore, at Job 33:4 we have essentially "the breath of God hath made me..."  And, at Ezek. 39:29 we should read it as "I have poured out my breath upon the house of Israel..."  And, at John 4:24 the words would be "God is a breath / wind..." more commonly written as "spirit" in the sense of a separate being.
The more complete understanding of "spirit" should be as a component part of YHVH, not as a separate entity.  This becomes more clear when we consider the full context of 1 John 4:1-3.

Beloved, every spirit believe not, but prove the spirits, if of God they are, because many false prophets have gone forth to the world; 2 in this know ye the Spirit of God; every spirit that doth confess Jesus Christ in the flesh having come, of God it is,


3 and every spirit that doth not confess Jesus Christ in the flesh having come, of God it is not; and this is that of the antichrist, which ye heard that it doth come, and now in the world it is already.  (YLT)

John was speaking about false prophets that were teaching false ideas.  False ideas are taught by men who speak false words.  Those are the spirits / words that come forth from the mouth or breath of men who deny God's Spirit, or God's breath, or God's word.  We are to test or prove the words of men against the words of God, and if the words of men do not agree with the breath or words of God, then they are false teachers and false prophets.
So, then what did God pour forth on the house of Israel in the old Mosaic covenant, but His words that were given to the prophets to speak to the house of Israel. Correspondingly, what did YHVH pour out onto the people of the first century AD but His words through John the Immerser, His Son Yeshua / Jesus, and through His disciples and apostles?  YHVH poured forth His words, His breath.
Excerpt from my post  Testing the Spirits - Part V(a) -

“Turn back at my reproof, lo, I pour forth to you my spirit, I make known my words with you.” (Prov. 1:23, YLT)

God’s poetry defines his synonyms and metaphors. They are usually couplets having two parts or lines. The first line or half of the couplet is repeated in different words in the second half. Thereby actions and objects are made equal to each other.
In Prov. 1:23, “pour forth” becomes “make known” and “my spirit” becomes “my words” in the second half. Therefore, God’s spirit equals God’s words, and pouring forth equals making known, or we could say revealing.
When God poured forth His Holy Spirit upon His prophets (messengers), He was putting His words directly into their minds, revealing to them His mind, which then poured out through the prophet’s mouths. They were God’s megaphone, His messengers.

“20this first knowing, that no prophecy of the Writing doth come of private exposition, 21for not by will of man did ever prophecy come, but by the Holy Spirit borne on holy men of God spake.” (2 Pet. 1:23, YLT)

The purpose of the Holy Spirit was always moving the men of God, His messengers to speak God’s words, to reveal God’s mind to the people. The Holy Spirit provides the Holy words of God, the mind of God.

“8the Spirit where he willeth doth blow, and his voice thou dost hear, but thou hast not known whence he cometh, and whither he goeth; thus is every one who hath been born of the Spirit.’


9Nicodemus answered and said to him, `How are these things able to happen?’


10Jesus answered and said to him, Thou art the teacher of Israel — and these things thou dost not know! 11Verily, verily, I say to thee — What we have known we speak, and what we have seen we testify, and our testimony ye do not receive;” (John 3:8-11, YLT)

The prophets of old were moved by the Holy Spirit to speak of what they heard and saw, to testify of both the words and the visions to the people. ....
So, let’s consider this question for a moment: did being filled with the Holy Spirit mean that the Holy Spirit occupied the prophet’s body? What does being “filled with the Holy Spirit” mean?

“9Jesus saith to him, `So long time am I with you, and thou hast not known me, Philip? he who hath seen me hath seen the Father; and how dost thou say, Shew to us the Father?


10Believest thou not that I [am] in the Father, and the Father is in me? the sayings that I speak to you, from myself I speak not, and the Father who is abiding in me, Himself doth the works;” (John 14:9-10, YLT)


“and be not conformed to this age, but be transformed by the renewing of your mind, for your proving what [is] the will of God — the good, and acceptable, and perfect.” (Rom. 12:2, YLT)


“5For, let this mind be in you that [is] also in Christ Jesus,…” (Phil. 2:5, YLT)


“And finally, being all of one mind, having fellow-feeling, loving as brethren, compassionate, courteous,” (1 Pet. 3:8 YLT)

How do we have the same mind that was in Christ Jesus?

“7now they have known that all things, as many as Thou hast given to me, are from Thee, 8because the sayings that Thou hast given to me, I have given to them, and they themselves received, and have known truly, that from Thee I came forth, and they did believe that Thou didst send me.” (John 17: 7-8, YLT)


“20`And not in regard to these alone do I ask, but also in regard to those who shall be believing, through their word, in me; 21that they all may be one, as Thou Father [art] in me, and I in Thee; that they also in us may be one, that the world may believe that Thou didst send me.” (John 17: 20-21, YLT)


“10but to us did God reveal [them] through His Spirit, for the Spirit all things doth search, even the depths of God, 11for who of men hath known the things of the man, except the spirit of the man that [is] in him? so also the things of God no one hath known, except the Spirit of God.


12And we the spirit of the world did not receive, but the Spirit that [is] of God, that we may know the things conferred by God on us, 13which things also we speak, not in words taught by human wisdom, but in those taught by the Holy Spirit, with spiritual things spiritual things comparing,


14and the natural man doth not receive the things of the Spirit of God, for to him they are foolishness, and he is not able to know [them], because spiritually they are discerned; 15and he who is spiritual, doth discern indeed all things, and he himself is by no one discerned;


16for who did know the mind of the Lord that he shall instruct Him? and we — we have the mind of Christ.” (1 Cor. 2:10-16, YLT)

“through their word”…We have the same mind of Christ through Christ’s spirit / words. We know His word because He spoke it, revealed it to us. Revealing equals making known. It is the knowing and abiding in His word that makes us of the same mind of Christ, that makes us one with Christ, and one with the Father.
Being filled with the Spirit = being filled with the word of God. Of the same mind of Christ = doing the will of the Father, abiding in His word.
In conclusion, as the scriptures show that YHVH's Spirit is His word, that His word blows where He wills it, and that we have His Spirit through His word, and can know His Spirit/word/breath by studying His scriptures, then are His scriptures part of the Trinity doctrine?  Or is it that His Spirit is simply His breath and the words He has given us through all of His messengers - the prophets, priests, John and Jesus, and all of the disciples and apostles?  Can we truly incorporate all of these messengers and prophets into a three body entity taught as the Trinity?
It seems the idea of the Trinity may be a false concept and should be reconsidered.

If you are going to cite John 3, then you should include verse 7: Do not marvel that I said to you, ‘You [plural] must be born again.’ This is in response to Nicodemus asking about entering his mother's womb a second time. Also there passages where the breath and/or wind blows understanding doesn't work. Then Jesus was led by the Spirit into the wilderness (Matthew 4:1)

Rom. 8:14, those who are led by the Spirit, these are the sons of God.  How r we led by the Spirit?  How r we led by the word of God?  How was Jesus led by the Spirit -the word God spoke to Him?  God told him to go to the wilderness? Gal. 5:18 - if by the Spirit ye are led, then ye are not under the law.  We are not under the law b/c we have obeyed the commands, the words of God to believe & be baptized into Christ.  Through the word of God, we have the mind of God & of His Son.  We r born spiritually thru the word of God by obeying His word to be immersed into Christ we become a new creature.

Further, being led means you r following some one or some thing.  Led by the Spirit, you r following the Spirit, the word of God.

I think we should be careful when comparing what we are to experience and what Jesus experienced. For example, he is the ὁ μονογενὴς υἱός, ὁ ὢν or ὁ μονογενὴς θεὸς, ὁ ὢν, we are not. He was born of a virgin. We are not. When He was baptized the Spirit descended on Him and remained. Our experience is to be baptized after believing and λαμβάνω the Spirit. So when Matthew chooses to describe being led by the Spirit and does so using different terminology than Luke and Mark, I don't think it is appropriate to understand the Spirit as your answer does.

My point is that I don't think the idea of the Trinity really comports with scripture.

Your answer makes that clear. I'm simply pointing out Scripture which does and in a way which contrasts with the belief Spirit is only wind or breath and a very real distinct entity.
